# How to block FeedReader from fetching my content to their site?

Tags: robots.txt

As you all can see from the picture below, my site's content is duplicated by FeedReader and indexed at Google. When I clicked at the FeedReader link, it uses some sort of iFrame to draw content from my site live. This forms some sort of content duplication to me, and I believe it does harm to my site.

[image]

[image]

(Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post image due to new account, pls click at the link above to see the picture, million thanks to you.)

What can I do to prevent Feedreader to fetch my content to their site? I know robots.txt can perform such function, but I don't know how to do it. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have also highlighted this issue to FeedReader 2 days ago, but yet to get any reply from them.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. So, I added the below code to my .htaccess to prevent bo.lt and feedreader.com from accessing my site.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bo.lt/ua [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} feedreader.com
RewriteRule . - [F,L]
```

When they try to access your site, it simply returns **403 forbidden**. You can also block it's IP by adding this to .htaccess.

```
deny from 67.210.247.197
deny from 67.210.247.247
deny from 67.210.247.193
deny from 67.210.247.196
```

Comment: I have been trying this, it doesn't seem to be working, I even inserted ip in Add an IP to deny in cpanel but not working, my sites content are duplicated and penalized by google.